# Hadoop MultipleOutputFormat support for with org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

Tags: hadoop

I'm a newbie in Hadoop!
Now I am trying to use MultipleOutputFormat with hadoop 2.2.0, but it seems they only work with deprecated 'JobConf' which in turn uses deprecated Mapper and Reducer (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer) etc., . Any ideas how to to acheive multiple output functionality with new 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job' ?

Comment: Use MultipleOutputs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JudgeMental noted, you should use `MultipleOutputs` with the new API (`mapreduce`) because `MultipleOutputFormat` only supports the old API (`mapred`). `MultipleOutputs` actually provides you more features than `MultipleOutputFormat`:

- With `MultipleOutputs`, each output can have its own `OutputFormat`, whereas with `MultipleOutputFormat` every output has to be the same `OutputFormat`.
- With `MultipleOutputFormat` you have more control over the naming scheme and output directory structure than `MultipleOutputs`.
- You can use `MultipleOutputs` in the `map` and `reduce` functions in the same job, something that you cannot do with `MultipleOutputFormat`.
- You can have different key and value types for different outputs with `MultipleOutputs`.

So both are not mutually exclusive, even if `MultipleOutputs` has more features, it is less flexible regrding the naming capabilities.

To learn how to use `MultipleOutputs`, you should just take a look at [this documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) which contains a complete example. In short, here is what you would put in the driver class:

```
// Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);

// Defines additional sequence-file based output 'sequence' for the job
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "seq", SequenceFileOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

And in your `Mapper` or `Reducer` you should just initialize your `MultipleOutputs` in the `setup` method with `MultipleOutputs mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);` and then you can use it in the `map` and `reduce` functions as `mos.write("seq", LongWritable(1), new Text("Bye"), "seq_a")`. Don't forget to close it in the `cleanup` method with `mos.close()` !