# How to write to different files based on content for batch processing in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to process some files on HDFS and write the results back to HDFS too. The files are already prepared before job starts. The thing is I want to write to different paths and files based on the file content. I am aware that `BucketingSink`([doc here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html)) is provided to achieve this in Flink streaming. However, it seems that `Dataset` does not have a similar API. I have found out some Q&As on stackoverflow.([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067959/can-flink-write-results-into-multiple-files-like-hadoops-multipleoutputformat/37454209), [2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11737), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209060/hadoop-multipleoutputformat-support-for-with-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-job)). Now I think I have two options:

1. Use Hadoop API: `MultipleTextOutputFormat` or `MultipleOutputs`;
2. Read files as stream and use `BucketingSink`.

My question is how to make a choice between them, or is there another solution ? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This question may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690095/how-to-generate-dynamic-path-in-dataset-during-the-output-method) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced the same problem. We too are surprised that `DataSet` does not support `addSink()`.

I recommend not switching to Streaming mode. You might give up some optimizations (i.e Memory pools) that are available in batch mode.

You may have to implement your own **OutputFormat** to do the bucketing.

Instead, you can extend the `OutputFormat[YOUR_RECORD]` (or `RichOutputFormat[]`) where you can still use the `BucketAssigner[YOUR_RECORD, String]` to open/write/close output streams.

That's what we did and it's working great.

I hope flink would support this soon in Batch Mode soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try.